# Peoplecode SQL update setting values on extra variables

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine, peoplecode

I modified the below Application Engine program, I added an additional field (`&ItmField`) to the CSV file layout that the program reads. It is correctly updating (SQL UPDATE) the field ITEM_FIELD_C10_B however I noticed in the Trace file that the SQL UPDATE statement is scripted to update the `SETID`, `INV_ITEM_ID`, and `ITEM_FIELD_C10_B` (Instead of just the field `ITEM_FIELD_C10_B`) WHERE `INV_ITEM_ID` is equal to `&InvItemId` and `SETID` is equal to "SHARE". The SQL Update **should** only be setting the `ITEM_FIELD_C10_B` field to `&ItmField` WHERE `INV_ITEM_ID` is equal to `&InvItemId` and `SETID` is equal to "SHARE".

Updated code is near the bottom beginning with "KDR - 10/11/18"
Trace code is also below.

```
Local SQL &SQL;
Local string &VendorId, &InvItemId, &ItmIdVndr, &UOM, &ConvRate, &PriceVndr, &Oprid, &PriceStatus, &VendorId_check, &insert_cols, &insert_select, &insert_where, &insert_sql, &Error, &MaxEffdt, &ItmField;
Local date &Effdt;
Local Record &ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR, &REC, &MASTER_ITEM_TBL;

&Oprid = "'BATCH'";
&PriceStatus = "2";
&Error = "N";

MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, "**** BEGINING OF VALIDATION ERRORS ****");

&SQL = CreateSQL("SELECT VENDOR_ID, INV_ITEM_ID, ITM_ID_VNDR, UNIT_OF_MEASURE, CONVERSION_RATE, PRICE_VNDR, %DateOut(EFFDT), ITEM_FIELD_C10_B FROM PS_GH_ITM_PR_UPDT ORDER BY VENDOR_ID, INV_ITEM_ID, ITM_ID_VNDR", &VendorId, &InvItemId, &ItmIdVndr, &UOM, &ConvRate, &PriceVndr, &Effdt, &ItmField);

While &SQL.Fetch(&VendorId, &InvItemId, &ItmIdVndr, &UOM, &ConvRate, &PriceVndr, &Effdt, &ItmField)

   SQLExec("SELECT A.VENDOR_ID FROM PS_ITM_VENDOR A, PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM B WHERE A.SETID = B.SETID AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = B.INV_ITEM_ID AND A.VENDOR_SETID = B.VENDOR_SETID AND A.VENDOR_ID = B.VENDOR_ID AND A.VENDOR_ID = :1 AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = :2 AND A.ITM_ID_VNDR = :3 AND A.ITM_VNDR_PRIORITY = 1 AND B.UNIT_OF_MEASURE = :4 AND B.CONVERSION_RATE = :5", &VendorId, &InvItemId, &ItmIdVndr, &UOM, &ConvRate, &VendorId_check);

   If None(&VendorId_check) Then;
      &Error = "Y";
      MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, &VendorId | " " | &InvItemId | " " | &ItmIdVndr | " " | &UOM | " " | &ConvRate | " " | &PriceVndr | " " | &Effdt | " " | &ItmField);
   Else;
      &CurrentDateTime = %Datetime;
      &Oprid = %OperatorId;
      &RECITEM = CreateRecord(Record.ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR);
      /*CHC Modification - Denise Smith - 8/8/2012 - CHC_PO_96588 - Begin */
      /*SQLExec("SELECT TO_CHAR(C.EFFDT,'DD-MON-YYYY') FROM PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR C WHERE C.INV_ITEM_ID = :1 AND C.VENDOR_ID = :2 AND C.UNIT_OF_MEASURE = :3 AND C.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(C1.EFFDT) FROM PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR C1 WHERE C.SETID = C1.SETID AND C.INV_ITEM_ID = C1.INV_ITEM_ID AND C.VENDOR_SETID = C1.VENDOR_SETID AND C.VENDOR_ID = C1.VENDOR_ID AND C.VNDR_LOC = C1.VNDR_LOC AND C.UNIT_OF_MEASURE = C1.UNIT_OF_MEASURE AND C.CURRENCY_CD = C1.CURRENCY_CD AND C.QTY_MIN = C1.QTY_MIN)  ", &InvItemId, &VendorId, &UOM, &MaxEffdt);*/
      SQLExec("SELECT C.EFFDT FROM PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR C WHERE C.INV_ITEM_ID = :1 AND C.VENDOR_ID = :2 AND C.UNIT_OF_MEASURE = :3 AND C.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(C1.EFFDT) FROM PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR C1 WHERE C.SETID = C1.SETID AND C.INV_ITEM_ID = C1.INV_ITEM_ID AND C.VENDOR_SETID = C1.VENDOR_SETID AND C.VENDOR_ID = C1.VENDOR_ID AND C.VNDR_LOC = C1.VNDR_LOC AND C.UNIT_OF_MEASURE = C1.UNIT_OF_MEASURE AND C.CURRENCY_CD = C1.CURRENCY_CD AND C.QTY_MIN = C1.QTY_MIN)  ", &InvItemId, &VendorId, &UOM, &MaxEffdt);
      /*CHC Modification - Denise Smith - 8/8/2012 - CHC_PO_96588 - End */
      SQLExec("%SelectAll(:1) WHERE INV_ITEM_ID = :2 AND VENDOR_ID = :3 AND UNIT_OF_MEASURE = :4 AND (CONVERT(CHAR(10),EFFDT,121)) = :5", &RECITEM, &InvItemId, &VendorId, &UOM, &MaxEffdt, &RECITEM);
      /*SQLExec("%SelectAll(:1) WHERE INV_ITEM_ID = :2 AND VENDOR_ID = :3 AND UNIT_OF_MEASURE = :4 AND EFFDT = :5", &RECITEM, &InvItemId, &VendorId, &UOM, &MaxEffdt, &RECITEM); */
      &new_UNIT_OF_MEASURE = &RECITEM.UNIT_OF_MEASURE.Value;
      &REC = CreateRecord(Record.ITM_VNDR_UOM_PR);
      &REC.SETID.Value = &RECITEM.SETID.Value;
      &REC.INV_ITEM_ID.Value = &RECITEM.INV_ITEM_ID.Value;
      &REC.VENDOR_SETID.Value = &RECITEM.VENDOR_SETID.Value;
      &REC.VENDOR_ID.Value = &RECITEM.VENDOR_ID.Value;
      &REC.VNDR_LOC.Value = &RECITEM.VNDR_LOC.Value;
      &REC.UNIT_OF_MEASURE.Value = &RECITEM.UNIT_OF_MEASURE.Value;
      &REC.CURRENCY_CD.Value = &RECITEM.CURRENCY_CD.Value;
      &REC.QTY_MIN.Value = &RECITEM.QTY_MIN.Value;
      &REC.EFFDT.Value = &Effdt;
      &REC.EFF_STATUS.Value = &RECITEM.EFF_STATUS.Value;
      &REC.PRICE_VNDR.Value = &PriceVndr;
      &REC.PCT_UNIT_PRC_TOL.Value = &RECITEM.PCT_UNIT_PRC_TOL.Value;
      &REC.PCT_EXT_PRC_TOL.Value = &RECITEM.PCT_EXT_PRC_TOL.Value;
      &REC.USE_STD_TOLERANCES.Value = &RECITEM.USE_STD_TOLERANCES.Value;
      &REC.QTY_RECV_TOL_PCT.Value = &RECITEM.QTY_RECV_TOL_PCT.Value;
      &REC.UNIT_PRC_TOL_L.Value = &RECITEM.UNIT_PRC_TOL_L.Value;
      &REC.PCT_UNIT_PRC_TOL_L.Value = &RECITEM.PCT_UNIT_PRC_TOL_L.Value;
      &REC.EXT_PRC_TOL_L.Value = &RECITEM.EXT_PRC_TOL_L.Value;
      &REC.PCT_EXT_PRC_TOL_L.Value = &RECITEM.PCT_EXT_PRC_TOL_L.Value;
      &REC.BU_PRICE_STATUS.Value = "2";
      &REC.STD_PRICE_STATUS.Value = "2";
      &REC.LEAD_TIME.Value = &RECITEM.LEAD_TIME.Value;
      &REC.OPRID_MODIFIED_BY.Value = &Oprid;
      &REC.LAST_DTTM_UPDATE.Value = &CurrentDateTime;
      &REC.PRICE_CHANGE.Value = &RECITEM.PRICE_CHANGE.Value;
      &REC.Insert();

   End-If;

   /* KDR - 10/11/2018 - Added field ITEM_FIELD_C10_B (&ItmField) to CSV file layout and insert into PS_MASTER_ITEM_TBL (&MASTER_ITEM_TBL) */
   If None(&ItmField) Then;
      &Error = "Y";
      MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, &VendorId | " " | &InvItemId | " " | &ItmIdVndr | " " | &UOM | " " | &ConvRate | " " | &PriceVndr | " " | &Effdt | " " | &ItmField);
   Else;
      &REC1 = CreateRecord(Record.MASTER_ITEM_TBL);
      &REC1.ITEM_FIELD_C10_B.Value = &ItmField;
      &REC1.SETID.Value = "SHARE";
      &REC1.INV_ITEM_ID.Value = &InvItemId;
      &REC1.Update();
   End-If;

End-While;
MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, "**** END OF VALIDATION ERRORS ****");
MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, " ");
```

**Trace code:**

```
131074   14:14:51.915     0.000000 Cur#1.37988.FSYS92T3 RC=0 Dur=0.000000 COM Stmt=UPDATE PS_MASTER_ITEM_TBL SET SETID=:1,INV_ITEM_ID=:2,ITEM_FIELD_C10_B=:3 WHERE SETID=:4 AND INV_ITEM_ID=:5
131075   14:14:51.915     0.000000 Cur#1.37988.FSYS92T3 RC=0 Dur=0.000000 Bind-1 type=2 length=5 value=SHARE
131076   14:14:51.916     0.001000 Cur#1.37988.FSYS92T3 RC=0 Dur=0.000000 Bind-2 type=2 length=5 value=68776
131077   14:14:51.916     0.000000 Cur#1.37988.FSYS92T3 RC=0 Dur=0.000000 Bind-3 type=2 length=8 value=86753090
131078   14:14:51.916     0.000000 Cur#1.37988.FSYS92T3 RC=0 Dur=0.000000 Bind-4 type=2 length=5 value=SHARE
131079   14:14:51.917     0.000000 Cur#1.37988.FSYS92T3 RC=0 Dur=0.000000 Bind-5 type=2 length=5 value=68776
131080   14:14:51.924     0.007000 Cur#1.37988.FSYS92T3 RC=0 Dur=0.007000 EXE
131081   14:14:51.924     0.000000 Cur#1.37988.FSYS92T3 RC=0 Dur=0.000000 ROW #rows=1
131082   14:14:51.925     0.000000 Cur#5.37988.FSYS92T3 RC=1 Dur=0.000000 Fetch
131083   14:14:51.925     0.000000 Cur#5.37988.FSYS92T3 RC=0 Dur=0.000000 Disconnect
```

**10/12/18 EDIT:**

If I add the SelectByKey as follows:

```
 /* KDR/TGC - 10/11/2018 - Added field ITEM_FIELD_C10_B (&ItmField) to CSV file layout and insert into PS_MASTER_ITEM_TBL (&MASTER_ITEM_TBL) */
   If None(&ItmField) Then;
      &Error = "Y";
      MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, &VendorId | " " | &InvItemId | " " | &ItmIdVndr | " " | &UOM | " " | &ConvRate | " " | &PriceVndr | " " | &Effdt | " " | &ItmField);
   Else;
      &REC1 = CreateRecord(Record.MASTER_ITEM_TBL);
      &REC1.ITEM_FIELD_C10_B.Value = &ItmField;
      &REC1.SETID.Value = "SHARE";
      &REC1.INV_ITEM_ID.Value = &InvItemId;
      If &REC1.SelectByKey() Then;
         &REC1.Update();
      End-If;
   End-If;
```

Then in my trace file I am seeing the following where it appears to be setting every field in the table to be updated:

```
132424   07:41:59.930     0.000000 Cur#1.37988.FSYS92T3 RC=0 Dur=0.000000 COM Stmt=UPDATE PS_MASTER_ITEM_TBL SET SETID=:1,INV_ITEM_ID=:2,ITM_STATUS_EFFDT=:3,ITM_STATUS_CURRENT=:4,ITM_STAT_DT_FUTURE=NULL,ITM_STATUS_FUTURE=:5,DESCR=:6,DESCR60=:7,DESCRSHORT=:8,UNIT_MEASURE_STD=:9,INV_ITEM_GROUP=:10,INV_PROD_FAM_CD=:11,CATEGORY_ID=:12,DATE_ADDED=:13,ORIG_OPRID=:14,APPROVAL_OPRID=:15,APPROVAL_DATE=:16,LAST_MAINT_OPRID=:17,LAST_DTTM_UPDATE=:18,CHANGE_FIELD=:19,INVENTORY_ITEM=:20,LOT_CONTROL=:21,SERIAL_CONTROL=:22,SHIP_SERIAL_CNTRL=:23,NON_OWN_FLAG=:24,APPROV_REQUIRED=:25,APPROV_SUBMITTED=:26,DENIAL_REASON=:27,STAGED_DATE_FLAG=:28,DIST_CFG_FLAG=:29,PRDN_CFG_FLAG=:30,CFG_CODE_OPT=:31,CFG_COST_OPT=:32,CFG_LOT_OPT=:33,CP_TEMPLATE_ID=:34,CP_TREE_DIST=:35,CP_TREE_PRDN=:36,CM_GROUP=:37,MATERIAL_RECON_FLG=:38,USG_TRCKNG_METHOD=:39,CONSIGNED_FLAG=:40,PL_PRIO_FAMILY=:41,ITEM_FIELD_C30_A=:42,ITEM_FIELD_C30_B=:43,ITEM_FIELD_C30_C=:44,ITEM_FIELD_C30_D=:45,ITEM_FIELD_C1_A=:46,ITEM_FIELD_C1_B=:47,ITEM_FIELD_C1_C=:48,ITEM_FIELD_C1_D=:49,ITEM_FIELD_C10_A=:50,ITEM_FIELD_C10_B=:51,ITEM_FIELD_C10_C=:52,ITEM_FIELD_C10_D=:53,ITEM_FIELD_C2=:54,ITEM_FIELD_C4=:55,ITEM_FIELD_C6=:56,ITEM_FIELD_C8=:57,ITEM_FIELD_N12_A=:58,ITEM_FIELD_N12_B=:59,ITEM_FIELD_N12_C=:60,ITEM_FIELD_N12_D=:61,ITEM_FIELD_N15_A=:62,ITEM_FIELD_N15_B=:63,ITEM_FIELD_N15_C=:64,ITEM_FIELD_N15_D=:65,PROMISE_OPTION=:66,DEVICE_TRACKING=:67,SERIAL_IN_PRDN=:68,TRACE_USAGE=:69,TRACE_CHANGE=:70,PHYSICAL_NATURE=:71 WHERE SETID=:72 AND INV_ITEM_ID=:73
```

Answer (score 0):

> The SQL Update should only be setting the ITEM_FIELD_C10_B field to &ItmField WHERE INV_ITEM_ID is equal to &InvItemId and SETID is equal to "SHARE".

This is effectively what the UPDATE statement is doing, as bind 1 equals bind 4 and bind 2 equals bind 5.

Now, because you select &InvItemId from a different table, you could add the following sanity check to make sure it exists in MASTER_ITEM_TBL: [SelectByKey](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13292_01/pt849pbr0/eng/psbooks/tpcr/htm/tpcr32.htm#g037ee99c9453fb39_ef90c_10c791ddc07__c85)

```
If &REC1.SelectByKey() Then
    &REC1.Update();
End-if;
```

The reason these fields are in your update statement is probably because the simplest way to implement the Record Class Update() Method would be: (speculation)

```
UPDATE TABLE SET (ALL SET FIELDS) WHERE (KEYS);
```

Because you are using a standalone record definition, rather than selecting from the buffer, the component processor doesn't know SETID and INV_ITEM_ID already exists, so it has to SET them.

Untested: Just adding `&REC1.SelectByKey()` before your `&REC1.Update()` may prevent this as it does a trip to the database.

Comment: Peter - Thanks for the feedback; Is there a way I can change the code so that I am only setting the `ITEM_FIELD_C10_B` field in the SQL update statement? If so, how so?

Comment: Have you traced with `&REC1.SelectByKey()`?

Comment: Yes I added it above in the post (10/12/18 EDIT:)  -however now it appears to be doing the sql update on every field in the table..

Comment: Peter I'm still new with understanding how the buffer and component processor works but would like to modify the code to update only the `ITEM_FIELD_C10_B` field, based on the `Where` conditions `INV_ITEM_ID` and `SETID`. Is this possible?

Comment: @JBinson88 sure, just use the SQLExec() function or look at the [SQL class](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26239_01/pt851h3/eng/psbooks/tpcr/chapter.htm?File=tpcr/htm/tpcr41.htm). I want to point out though that you say "it appears to be setting every field in the table to be updated", but the statement is updating them to their current value, so they don't actually change.